# Deflection of a freely falling body

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, coriolis-effect

Why Coriolis force acts on a freely falling body on earth as it is not in contact of earth surface?
if a body being in contact of earth surface will suffer Coriolis force for earth's rotation 
but in case of a freely falling body, the body is not in contact of earth surface 
then why Coriolis force acts on a freely falling body?

Comment: It is not a real force, it is an illusion due to your own movement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_effect

Comment: @brucesmitherson clarification: due to the movement of the observer, presumably attached to the (moving) surface of the earth.

Comment: Coriolis force always there when a body is moving/translating in a rotating frame.

Comment: @DanielGriscom for some reason I tend to answer as if the OP were the moving observer, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: if it is for the movement of the observer attached with the surface of the earth it's deflection should be towards west .but I heard that deflection occurs towards east.  then why it is so?

Comment: then what should be the direction of deflection of an object appears to an observer moving with earth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For on observer from space a falling object falls in straight line. But for an observer moving with the earth it appears to deflect toward one side.

Since real forces only affect movement in an inertial frame, and on the inertial frame there is no deflection, thus there is no force acting on a moving body (except aerodynamic forces).